# Windows file path in cURL commands

Tags: curl, cmd

In cmd.exe, I'm trying to issue a command to localhost and also write a cookie file. The connection to localhost seems OK but the cookie file isn't being written. The command looks something like this:

```
curl --cookie C:\\path\to\cookie --cookie-jar C:\\path\to\cookie --data "{'username':'admin', 'password':'1234'}" http://localhost:8443/api/login
```

I'm guessing I'm getting file path wrong? Write permissions are set correctly... Unless cURL itself requires permissions?

**UPDATE:**

Based on suggestions, I tried this but it also isn't working:

```
curl --cookie C:/path/to/cookie --cookie-jar C:/path/to/cookie --data "{'username':'admin', 'password':'1234'}" http://localhost:8443/api/login
```

I also tried with quotes around the paths, but that didn't work either.

Comment: imo, _always use forward slash ('/') in **windows**:  filepaths, network paths_ etc.. You may need to put them in quotes(") when using the CLI. But they always work. i.e. `"C:/path/to/cookie"`.

Comment: Tried with forward slashes both with and without quotes, but the file still isn't being created and written to. Now I'm wondering if there's a configuration issue...

Comment: I have the same issue. My workaround is to run it from the bash (as part of MinGW), in which case it works even with Windows style paths (no quotes, and with backslash).

Answer (score -2):

Did you put the curl install folder (path) into the windows system "Environment Variables" Path? In my case it was `C:\Program Files (x86)\Curl Corporation\Surge\9\bin`

Windows 10 and Windows 8

- In Search, search for and then select: System (Control Panel)
  Click the Advanced system settings link.
- Click Environment Variables. In the section System Variables, find the PATH environment variable and select it. Click Edit. If the PATH environment variable does not exist, click New.

I just installed cUrl on my Windows 10 system and it would not run and not throw an error either. Once I put the cUrl install folder in the "Environment Variables / System Variables" Path, it worked for me.